# Scrolling to a point when WebBrowser is zoomed

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, browser, zooming

I'm trying to zoom into a picture on a webpage loaded in the .Net WebBrowser control.
For example, there's a picture at `(100,100)` on 100% zoom. Now I want to set the zoom to 200% and have the picture at the top left in the WebBrowser control.

It almost works. If the point is on the left side of the screen it works. But if the point is more to the right of the screen, new calculated points are not correct.
Y is always correct. Only the X is giving me problems.

Anyone know how the ScrollTo is related to the current zoom factor. Or is it also related to other variables? I suspect the problem is also the adaptation of the webpage related to the size of the screen. (on zooming it removes the left and right edge of a webpage that doesn't hold any information. After that it enlarges the content). I need true zoom where the scaling affects only the content, not the layout. There is no reflow caused when scaling.

```
public class MyBrowser : WebBrowser

    private int _zoom = 100;
    public int Zoom
    {
        set
        {
            _zoom = value;

            //perform zoom
            object pvaIn = _zoom;
            try
            {
                this._axIWebBrowser2.ExecWB(
                    OLECMDID.OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM,
                    OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,
                    ref pvaIn, 
                    IntPtr.Zero);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _zoom;
        }
    }

    private Point GetCurrentScroll()
    {
        int scrollX = this.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].ScrollLeft;
        int scrollY = this.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].ScrollTop;

        return new Point(scrollX, scrollY);
    }

    public void ZoomOnPoint(int x, int y, int zoomFactor)
    {
        int currentZoom = this.Zoom;

        Point currentScroll = GetCurrentScroll();

        //Set new values
        this.Zoom = newZoom;
        this.Document.Window.ScrollTo(
            currentScroll.X + ((x * currentZoom) / zoomFactor), //X is sometimes correct, mostly on the rightside of the screen
            currentScroll.Y + y);                               //Y is correct
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's a `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` then its `Document` property is of type `object`. How are you getting a `Window` property from it?

Comment: Document is of type HtmlDocument: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Oh we're talking about Windows Forms. I was thinking of WPF.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, I multiply the X and Y values with the H and V zoom perc, it works :)